# How can I get addresses from a specific country / state / political division in Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am developing an application that uses the Google Maps API, and the user set an address and the application finds different and possible addresses that match the address that the user entered, but I want the address of a specific city, state or country if it is possible.

For example: 
I want to find the address "Washington Ave.", Google Maps find some address:

- "Washington Avenue, Filadelfia, Pensilvania"
- "Washington Avenue, New Orleans, Louisiana"
- "Washington Avenue, Houston, Texas"

But, what if I want just results inside Houston City? Or Pensilvania?, Or another country?

I have this Java code in Android Studio that finds a possible address that matches a String (address written by the user), and the possible options can only show 5, and it returns the latitude and longitude of the address written by the user

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName("Manuel de la Peña y Peña 805-835, Bella Vista, 64410 Monterrey, N.L.", 5);
if(addresses.size() > 0) {
    double latitude= addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
    double longitude= addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
}
```

So, how can I find addresses inside a specifically a citiy, state or country in Google Maps API for Android?

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should only be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get addresses located inside a certain area you should use a service that supports strict bounds for address search. Currently strict bounds are supported in place autocomplete service and you can find documentation in Places SDK for Android:

https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically

The idea is create a rectangular bounds object that matches the city or region you are interested in and use strict bound filters when you search address predictions.

The code snippet is the following. Note `setLocationRestriction` and `setCountry` filters when you construct a prediction request

```
AutocompleteSessionToken token = AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance();

// Create a RectangularBounds object for area you are interested in.
RectangularBounds bounds = RectangularBounds.newInstance(
    new LatLng(-33.880490, 151.184363),
    new LatLng(-33.858754, 151.229596));
// Use the builder to create a FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.
FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest request = FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
// Call setLocationRestriction() with bounds in order to restrict search to given area.
    .setLocationRestriction(bounds)
    .setCountry("au")
    .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS)
    .setSessionToken(token)
    .setQuery(query)
    .build();

placesClient
    .findAutocompletePredictions(request)
    .addOnSuccessListener((response) -> {
        for (AutocompletePrediction prediction : response.getAutocompletePredictions()) {
            Log.i(TAG, prediction.getPlaceId());
            Log.i(TAG, prediction.getPrimaryText(null).toString());
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener((exception) -> {
        if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
            ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
            Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: " + apiException.getStatusCode());
        }
    });
```

For further details please have a look at Places SDK for Android documentation.

I hope this helps!